# Thymeleaf hidden input value is always null

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to put hidden inmput with value in form but the filed is always null.

```
<form th:action="@{/user/subject/join}" th:object="${joinSubjectDTO}" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password to subject:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" th:field="*{password}" /></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" th:field="*{subjectId}" th:value="${subject.id}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="submit">Join</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Could anyone help me with this issue ?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JoinSubjectDTO {
    private Integer subjectId;
    private String password;
}
```

I'm adding JoinSubjectDTO class.

Comment: `th:field` overwrites the `name`, `id` and `value` of an input.  If you want to default `subjectId` then you should set it on the controller before the html is rendered.  You cannot mix `th:field` and `th:value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working code is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="subjectId" th:value="${subject.id}">
```

Comment: I replaced name with id and it worked fine :)

Comment: `name` works for me, `id` works not for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try just below line. No need to take td tag. Write hidden tag out side of table. Also don't specify th:value, as t:field it self is id, name and value.

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{subjectId}">
```

Comment: it didn't help, the value is still null

Comment: Can you please display your JoinSubjectDTO class? Also, log your object at class level to confirm that value is available in subjectId or subject.id?

Comment: I added JoinSubjectDTO class to question, and i was checking subject.id value and it is available.

Comment: Are you sure that your value is available in subject.id ? then just edit above answer to <input type="hidden" th:field="${subject.id}">, it is possible only if you are also passing subject object in modal from controller along with joinSubjectDTO.

Comment: subject is a diffrent object with field id and I want to pass this value to joinSubjectDTO object to field subjectId, I'm sure that subject.id is available because i printed it on screen for test and value is correct